# How to implement "if (TargetToFind != null)" in my code to fix "Missing Reference Exception: error message

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making this game for school and I ran into this problem. I've researched it but cant find anyone in the same situation as me.

I'm pretty new to all this Unity and MonoDevelop stuff so I don't know what to try. Nothing online has told me or guided me to where exactly I should place the new code within my already existing code.

Although I am sure it should be placed within the code that is in charge of the camera movement.

Movement of Camera in regards to player:

```
public class MoveCamera : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform target;

    public float smoothSpeed = 0.125f;
    public Vector3 offset;

    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        Vector3 desiredPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothedPostion = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, desiredPosition, smoothSpeed);
        transform.position = smoothedPostion;

        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

and Player/user Movement:

```
private Rigidbody rb;

void Start () 
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
}

void FixedUpdate () {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().velocity = new Vector3 (0, 0, 20);

    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");

    Vector3 Movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    rb.AddForce (Movement*Speed);
}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Obstacle")
    {
       Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Right now, since I'm pretty early in on this project, it hasn't caused any major errors. But I'm afraid that as i progress without fixing this problem that it'll ruin the game.

The error that comes up is "MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object."

Comment: you need to manually set `MoveCamera.target` to null. destroy destroys the unity object, but not the c# object you still reference. aside of that, you probably dont want to destroy the player anyway. why not just disable it?

Answer (score 2):

In OnColissionEnter you destroy the player.
But the camera is trying to get acces to it (`target`).
As in the debugger is said you have 2 options:
one is that you don't destroy your GameObject,
or you stop the game when you are destroyed.
You could also check in the fixedupdate if the target still exists:

```
if (!target)
{
    return;
}
```

I hope I helped you.